# Trigger something only if the tab is not active

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using function

```
$(window).on("blur focus", function(e) {
    var prevType = $(this).data("prevType"); // getting identifier to check by
    if (prevType != e.type) {   //  reduce double fire issues by checking identifier
        switch (e.type) {
            case "blur":
                flashTitle(from + " messaged you", 500);
                break;
            case "focus":
                cancelFlashTitle();
                break;
        }
    }
    $(this).data("prevType", e.type); // reset identifier
})
```

I want the flash title triggered ONLY when the user is not looking at the tab. Means like the tab is not focused now. **Right now the flash title triggered only when I focus the tab first and then leave(blur) it.**

Any ideas? Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you would want to flash the title upon getting a new message if the tab is not focused, since the message is the event that's happening, and then cancel any flashing on focus.

Comment: @jackhao What I meant is that your code is watching for window events, but what it should be watching for is message events. A message event is what should trigger that whole block. I can't write the code because I don't know how your system works.